# hudson(CI) plugins for failed build

Tags: plugins, hudson

Is there any plugins can detect the build fails and then run next certain job? what i try to do is let hudson run one job after current job build successfully, run another job if current build fails.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The "Hudson Parameterized Trigger plugin" should be what you are locking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is the 'Retry Failed Builds Plugin' allows you to retry failed Hudson builds every n minutes.
But in my knowledge, there is no possibility to invoke another job when a job fails.
What is your exactly need?